# Generate center point in a field

Tags: fme-form

On shapefile data, I had used center point extractor using point mode center and add StringConcatenator with result string 2201@Value(_inside_x)@Value(inside_y).

After that I get the result 2201158707510.139225325713360.34431
where _x value is 158707510.139225 , _y value is 325713360.34431 and 2201 is constant value.

I want to remove after decimal values in the result and want result as 2201158707510325713360.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or for a transformer solution use the AttributeRounder, like so:

[image]

...rounding to 0 places will give you integer values for the centre x/y

Comment: Could you expand your answer to include how the AttributeRounder is used

Comment: Done. Added a screenshot and a little more info

Answer (score 3):

To remove the decimal values, just round:

```
@round(<FLOAT>)
```

in your case:

```
2201@round(@Value(_inside_x))@round(@Value(_inside_y))
```